# Creating multiple datasets with R function

Tags: r, function, parameters, lapply

I created the following function that takes 3 numeric parameters, size of longitude (in degrees), size of latitude (in degrees) and year. The function creates squares (grids) of size denoted by the first two parameters and then allocates the observations in the dataset over those grids, seperated by year (the third parameter). The function is working as intended.

To use the function to construct a 2x2 Assemblage (the grid with the all the observations in it) for the year 2009, I call:

```
assemblage_2009 <- CreateAssembleage(2, 2, 2009)
```

**However**, I would like to create assembleages iteratively from the year 2009 to 2018.

I tried to do a for loop with `i in 2009:2018` without much success. I also tried `lapply` but also without much success.

Any ideas from more experienced R users?

The function:

```
CreateAssembleage <- function(size_long, size_lat, year){
  
  # create a dataset to hold only values with the chosen year
  data_grid_year <- dplyr::filter(data_grid, Year == year)

  
  # Create vectors to hold the columns (easier to work with)
  Longitude <- data_grid_year$Longitude 
  Latitude <- data_grid_year$Latitude
  
  dx <- size_long # set up the dimensions (easier to change here than inside the code)
  dy <- size_lat 
  
  # construct the grids
  gridx <- seq(min(Longitude), max(Longitude), by = dx) # the values we discussed for the big square
  gridy <- seq(min(Latitude), max(Latitude), by = dy)
  
  # take the data and create 3 new columns (x, y, cell) by finding the specified data inside the constructed grids
  grid_year <- data_grid_year %>% 
    mutate(
      x = findInterval(Longitude, gridx),
      y = findInterval(Latitude, gridy),
      cell = paste(x, y, sep = ",")) %>% 
    relocate(Sample_Id, Latitude, Longitude, x, y, cell) # bring forward the new columns

  ### Create the assemblage  
  data_temp <- grid_year %>% 
    group_by(cell) %>% # group by the same route id
    select(-c(Sample_Id, Latitude, Longitude, Midpoint_Date_Local,
              Year, Month, Chlorophyll_Index, x, y)) %>%  # remove unneeded columns
    summarise(across(everything(), sum)) # calculate the sum
  
  return(data_temp) #return the result
}
```

Thank you all for any ideas.

Comment: What did your attempts using a `for` loop or `lapply` look like? What exactly does "much success" mean? Did you get an error?

Comment: Hi ... I go with @MrFlick ... you have a `wonderful function`, congrats. But it is unclear what does not work. Have you tried to understand how to supply the values for your functions to make the loop roll, and how to you collect the different results? Give it a try to understand how the loop functions work (i.e. taking values) and supplying them to a function, and then return results to be stored in an object.

Comment: @MrFlick no I did not get an error... my for loop is the following ```for (i in 2009:2018) {
  assembleges <- list(CreateAssembleage(2, 2, i))
}```, which returns a list with only one item (I suppose the last iteration of the loop). I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You overwrite the same object every time in your loop. But adding new items in a loop can be inefficient if you don't preallocate the list fist. I'd recommend the `lapply` method that Manuel  has shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot check whether your function works since I don't have any data from you. This said, there are multiple possibilities to call a function n times and save the output.
Since you didn't specify the problem, I have to assume you struggle to run the function in a loop and save the output.
Also, I'll have to assume that 1st: your function works, 2nd: `size_long` and `size_lat` are always set to 2. If you have different ideas, you'll have to make more clear what you want.

Some options:

1. Create a list with the output using `lapply`. Note that here, you'll have to set `size_long = 2, size_lat = 2` when you define the function, so these values are the standard values. Furthermore, make `year` the first argument.

```
years <- 2009:2018
results <- lapply(years, CreateAssembleage)
```

2. Create a list with the output using a for loop:

```
results <- list()
for(i in 2009:2018){
list[[paste0("assemblage_", i)]] <- CreateAssembleage(size_long = 2, size_lat = 2, year = i)
}
```

3. If need be, create multiple variables, one for each year:

```
for(i in 2009:2018){
do.call("<-", list(paste0("assemblage_", i), CreateAssembleage(size_long = 2, size_lat = 2,
        year = i)))
}
```

4. Same as 3. but using `assign`:

```
for(i in 2009:2018){
assign(paste0("assemblage_", i), CreateAssembleage(size_long = 2, size_lat = 2, year = i))
}
```

Note that if you want to alter not only `year` but also the other variables each time, e.g., change `size_lat` for each iteration, you'll have to use `mapply` instead of `lapply`, or, in case of the loops, you'll have to create vectors (or a dataframe) with the other variables as well and adjust your loop.

**Edit**: As suggested by MrFlick, I changed the order of the options and added the `assign`-option. Loops are easier to understand for most beginners, but they can be annoyingly slow for large datasets. So it is probably best to get used to `lapply`.

Comment: Rather than `do.call(\`<-\`), in #2, a more idomatic way in R is to use `assign()`. Though using lists is way better for most operations. I think your #3 should be your #1 recommendation.

Comment: The ```lapply``` method works perfectly. Thank you. When I was trying this method I tried to pass all three arguments to the function and I simply couldn't.

Comment: I ended up using method #1 because I want to be able to adjust the grid size as well. Thank you all for your inputs.